# cmake find package can not see Qt6

Tags: cmake, config, qt6, find-package

I downloaded qt6 -> qtbase only and built, install it  , i write simple program to check it,
when I tried to locate Qt6 it show me this error :

- CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
- Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible
- with requested version "".
- The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
- F:/Work/ToolChain/qt5/install/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake, version: 6.0.4 (32bit)
- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

  CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.20)
  project(QT_FP)

  ```
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

   list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  "F:/Work/ToolChain/qt5/install/lib/cmake")

   find_package(Qt6 CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTES Core)

   set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
   set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
   set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

   file(GLOB SRC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
   file(GLOB INC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp)
   file(GLOB UIS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.ui)

   add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
   target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SRC} ${INC} ${UIS} )
   target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Core)
  ```

Comment: "F:/Work/ToolChain/qt5/install/lib/cmake" I see qt5 in this path ;)

Comment: @Mizux Qt 6 repo is still named `qt5`. Anyway I see a typo in `COMPONENTES` it should be `COMPONENTS` and the `CONFIG` looks misplaced. And possibly you want `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to point to `"F:/Work/ToolChain/qt5/install"`. But it is hard to give a definitive answer, it could be a corrupted Qt install.